# How to add an <asp:button> to a jquery ui dialog containing an iframe

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe, jquery-dialog

This is how my dialog is generated:

```
$(function () {
    $(".btnDialog").click(function() {
        //e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $('<iframe id="PDFDialog"  frameborder="0" src="' + this.href + '" />').dialog({
            title: ($this.attr('title')) ? $this.attr('title') : 'External Site',
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 700,
            height: 600,
            modal: true,
            resizable: true,
            overlay: {
                opacity: 0.5,
                background: "black"
            }
        }).width(650).height(550);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Where and how do i add any server controls such as `<asp:label runat="server">` and `< asp:button runat="server">`???

Comment: That is not possible. You can add HTML controls and add jQuery click events to generate a post or AJAX post, or you can add the controls as normal and use jQuery to hide/display those controls, but you can't dynamically construct a server-side control with jQuery.

Comment: Are you trying to add a button to open the popup or trying to add a button to the popup?

Comment: im trying to add a button under the iframe inside of my dialog. So to answer your question, im trying to add a button to the popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is create a new aspx page, for instance Dialog.aspx, and put your `asp:Label`, `asp:Button`, etc. controls on that page.  Then set your iframe's src to the aspx page:

`$('<iframe id="PDFDialog" frameborder="0" src="Dialog.aspx" />').dialog //...`